# Data sent via Neo4j rest api does not get persisted

Tags: neo4j, cypher, data-storage, neo4jrestclient

I'm using Neo4j rest api to create a graph structure with a larger number of nodes and relationships. I used the following cypher query format to send a batch of nodes and their relationships in a single post request.

```
UNWIND [[0,1], [0,6309]] AS pair
MATCH (n {name: pair[0]}), (m {name: pair[1]})
CREATE (n)-[:X]->(m)
```

I'm reading data from a file of 1GB size and uploading the data batch-wise to neo4j. I get response code 200 for all the requests that I send but when I checked the `{$NEO4J_HOME}/data/databases/graph.db` size it shows only 244K size. Also `du -hc *store.db*` command inside graph.db showed that all the nodestore.db, relationshipstore.db and propertystore.db sizes are 0. Why does the data that is uploaded via rest api not get written to files in the graph DB? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Output from `du -hc *store.db*`

```
0       neostore.nodestore.db
4.0K    neostore.nodestore.db.id
8.0K    neostore.nodestore.db.labels
4.0K    neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id
0       neostore.propertystore.db
8.0K    neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
4.0K    neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id
4.0K    neostore.propertystore.db.id
8.0K    neostore.propertystore.db.index
4.0K    neostore.propertystore.db.index.id
8.0K    neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys
4.0K    neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id
0       neostore.relationshipstore.db
```

This is the complete request sent to neo4j rest api using jersey client.

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user, password));
WebResource cypherResource = client.resource("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher");
ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypherResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).entity(query).post(ClientResponse.class);
```

Sample query set as entity :

```
{"query":"UNWIND [[0,1], [0,6309]] AS pair
MATCH (n {name: pair[0]}), (m {name: pair[1]}) CREATE (n)-[:X]->(m)"}
```

Comment: Show us the complete query (method, path, headers, body) sent to Neo4j. Maybe you're never committing the transaction?

Comment: I have updated the question with the complete query I send to Neo4j. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got side-tracked by the REST context, when actually the query wouldn't work in any context (REST API, Neo4j browser, neo4j-shell, etc.).

According to the size of all the files, there aren't any relationship **or nodes** in the database. Your query starts by matching on nodes: since there aren't any, the `CREATE` clause will never be executed.

To create the nodes that don't already exist, and then the relationship, you need to use [`MERGE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-merge) instead of `MATCH`. You should also set a label on the nodes, and for performance and correctness, create a [unicity constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-constraints-unique-nodes) on the `name` property for that label (it will create an index at the same time):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE;
```

then:

```
UNWIND [[0,1], [0,6309]] AS pair
MERGE (n:Node {name: pair[0]})
MERGE (m:Node {name: pair[1]})
CREATE (n)-[:X]->(m)
```

(or use `MERGE` for the relationship as well if there can be duplicate pairs in the file).

Are you aware of the [`LOAD CSV`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-load-csv) Cypher clause, which could import data faster than your remote queries, even if you batch pairs manually?

Comment: thanks for your solution. I tried this approach and it seems to work correctly. The neostore files gets updated from the data that I send and I'm using several threads to concurrently post data batch-wise. However for the data-set with 1GB size it took nearly 3 hours and still its uploading. 
I'm aware of the `LOAD CSV` option but i have to use the rest api to compare the performance of neo4j with another graph database for streaming graphs.